# Passing a v-slot value to the same element

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex, buefy

I'm using Buefy grid and trying to pass props from v-slot to another attribute in the same element but I get an error saying "props is undefined" even though it's right above it. Any ideas on how to solve this bug?

```
<b-table :data="rowsData">

  <b-table-column
           v-slot="props"
           :cell-class="props.row.showDetail ? 'selected-row': ''"
           >
  </b-table-column>

</b-table>
```

Here's the error I'm getting
[image]

Comment: the code seems to be correct, according Buefy to documentation. Do you use Vue v2.6?

Comment: Yes, I'm using vue "^2.6.10". When I use props inside the <b-table-column> element it works but it doesn't when I use it in the starting tag

Comment: hmm, that is an important point, i think you just can't use scoped slot props on the element itself, interesting

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
v-slot='{props}'
```

or

```
v-slot='item'
:cell-class="item.props.row.showDetail ? 'selected-row': ''"
```

You need to dereference props.

Comment: We will get this working @MahmoudFarargy, but you need to provide more of a working example. It is not clear what your parent element is.

Comment: It's alright. I have found another way to dynamically add or remove the 'selected-row' class by using Vanilla Javascript. It's working fine and not related to slots. Thanks guys.